# How to get the full list of Modernizr features

Tags: javascript, modernizr

Is there any way to get a list of all features detected by Modernizr?

The current naming of features is very unintuitive, for example to check for feature "canvas" you just have to call `Modernizr.canvas` but in order to check for "forms-placeholder" or "forms_placeholder" (it depends on whether you check for the feature's name on the page or in the generated code) you have to call `Modernizr.placeholder`

There seems to be no rule in the naming of features. I couldn't even find a complete reference of all these features, especially the "non-core" ones. The documentation on [modernizr.com](http://modernizr.com/docs/) is very poor. It also lacks a good tutorial. All I can do is simply guess it's names, since only some of them are included as the class names for the `<html>` tag (for example, you won't find "Input Types" or "Input Attributes" there).

All I need is to call some functions only when specific feature is supported, for example:

```
if(Modernizr.canvas){
 // draw canvas
}
```

I tried to detect whether the browser supports `.toDataURL('image/png')` function, but the Modernizr script returns only "todataurljpeg" and "todataurlwebp", even though the "todataurlpng" is somwhere [in there](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/canvas/todataurl.js).

How can I retrieve all the `Modernizer.features` names via JavaScript? Any links to some good references or tutorials will be appreciated (obviously not the ones from the Modernizr home page).

Comment: have you tried `console.log(Modernizr)`?

Comment: I didn't know that method, I just googled it. Now I came up with few objects that are still inaccessible, like `input` or `inputtypes`. They are arrays, but I don't know how to call specific values (for example `inputtypes.email`). And still there is no "todataurlpng" there.

Answer (score 1):

I think your biggest problem is you're mixing up your versions. In the current stable tag, 2.8.1, this is the test for `todataurl`:

```
// canvas.toDataURL type support
// http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl

// This test is asynchronous. Watch out.

(function () {

    if (!Modernizr.canvas) {
        return false;
    }

    var image = new Image(),
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    image.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        Modernizr.addTest('todataurljpeg', function() {
            return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').indexOf('data:image/jpeg') === 0;
        });
        Modernizr.addTest('todataurlwebp', function() {
            return canvas.toDataURL('image/webp').indexOf('data:image/webp') === 0;
        });
    };

    image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAACklEQVR4nGMAAQAABQABDQottAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
}());
```

(source: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/v2.8.1/feature-detects/canvas-todataurl-type.js)

You'll notice in particular that 'todataurlpng' is *not* present.

Now, here's the test in master (3.0 beta):

```
/*!
{
  "name": "canvas.toDataURL type support",
  "property": ["todataurljpeg", "todataurlpng", "todataurlwebp"],
  "tags": ["canvas"],
  "builderAliases": ["canvas_todataurl_type"],
  "async" : false,
  "notes": [{
    "name": "HTML5 Spec",
    "href": "http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl"
  }]
}
!*/
define(['Modernizr', 'createElement', 'test/canvas'], function( Modernizr, createElement ) {

  var canvas = createElement('canvas');

  Modernizr.addTest('todataurljpeg', function() {
    return !!Modernizr.canvas && canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').indexOf('data:image/jpeg') === 0;
  });
  Modernizr.addTest('todataurlpng', function() {
    return !!Modernizr.canvas && canvas.toDataURL('image/png').indexOf('data:image/png') === 0;
  });
  Modernizr.addTest('todataurlwebp', function() {
    return !!Modernizr.canvas && canvas.toDataURL('image/webp').indexOf('data:image/webp') === 0;
  });

});
```

(source: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/canvas/todataurl.js)

There it is!

The docs are better than you think, but 3.0 beta is a major rewrite and the docs have not been updated (mostly because it hasn't actually been released, yet). Just keep in mind that if you see something you think should be there or isn't mentioned in the docs, it's probably something *new* in the beta.

As for a list of all the feature detections, there's the [docs](http://modernizr.com/docs/#s2), which is still your safest bet. I also [found this nifty site](http://www.browserleaks.com/modernizr), but it appears that, despite what it says in the description, the tool is referencing the master branch, and is thus, pulling from 3.0 beta with all the new and changed detects. So it might be a little off-putting for now.

Comment: OK, I didn't notice that the source I provided was for the beta version, I am using the current 2.8.1 version. But still the docs are terrible, they do not cover even a half of the functions that are available in the code generator and when they do - the descriptions are terse. For example, there is no explanation on how to call specific values, like e.g. `Modernizr.input.required`

Comment: Re: there is no explanation on how to call specific values, like e.g. `Modernizr.input.required` - there isn't anything to "call" you just check its value like any other. eg if (Modernizr.input.required) {//do something}

Comment: @Patrick That's exactly what I was asking for. Strange, but I tried your example before and it didn't worked - now it works somehow...
I don't understand why, but previously I was unable to pass the `Modernizr.inputtypes` test (`datetime` returned false). That's why I wanted to choose only specific input types & attributes for my tests. And now the browser passes `Modernizr.inputtypes` test even though the `datetime` still returns false. That's beyond me... :/